# Checking the input to match fact in Clips

Tags: input, clips

I have a problem with trying to get an input and fact-check it with symptoms in the asserted facts.

```
(deftemplate disease
(slot name)
(multislot symptom ))

(assert (disease 
(name nitro-def) (symptom stunted-growth pale-yellow reddish-brown-leaf)))
(assert (disease 
(name phosphor-def) (symptom stunted-root-growth spindly-stalk purplish-colour)))
(assert (disease 
(name potassium-def) (symptom purple-colour weakened-stems shriveled-seeds)))

(defrule reading-input
(disease (name ?name1) (symptom ?symptom1))
=>
(printout t "Enter the symptom your plant exhibits: " )
(assert (var (read))))

(defrule checking-input
?vars <- (var)
(disease (name ?name1) (symptom ?symptom1))
(disease (symptom ?vars&:(eq ?vars ?symptom1)))
=>
(printout t "Disease is " ?name1 crlf))
```

So basically you input a symptom and Clips returns the disease that matches that symptom. Problem is, that after *Loading the file as Batch* and running it, nothing happens. The Facts are asserted but no input is required. Nothing even touches the first rule.

If anyone can help me in this issue, I would be dully grateful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined symptom as a multifield slot (a slot containing zero or more fields), but your patterns matching those slots will only match if the slot contains a single field. Use a multifield variable such as $?symptom1 instead of a single field variable such as ?symptom1 to retrieve multiple values.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate disease
   (slot name)
   (multislot symptom))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts diseases
   (disease (name nitro-def) 
            (symptom stunted-growth pale-yellow reddish-brown-leaf))
   (disease (name phosphor-def) 
            (symptom stunted-root-growth spindly-stalk purplish-colour))
   (disease (name potassium-def) 
            (symptom purple-colour weakened-stems shriveled-seeds)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule reading-input
   =>
   (printout t "Enter the symptom your plant exhibits: " )
   (assert (var (read))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule checking-input
   (var ?symptom)
   (disease (name ?name1) (symptom $?symptom1))
   (test (member$ ?symptom ?symptom1)) 
   =>
   (printout t "Disease is " ?name1 crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Enter the symptom your plant exhibits: stunted-growth
Disease is nitro-def
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Enter the symptom your plant exhibits: purplish-colour
Disease is phosphor-def
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Enter the symptom your plant exhibits: spindly-stalk
Disease is phosphor-def
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks alot Mr. Gary!
Analizing your code made me realise the mistakes I made. Ugh, countless hours of attempting to make this input/match and still, I would've stayed until 4 AM and still wouldn't manage to make it work. 

Thanks alot sir!